# Problema con resultado AJAX en una regla required de jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Tengo un incidente con una respuesta que tengo en un AJAX, todo esto dentro de un `depends` de una regla `required` en un JS con [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) para la validación de un formulario.

Les dejo el código que estoy ejecutando:

```
$('#form').validate({
  ignore: '[readonly=readonly]',
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'), newError = $(error).text();
    $(element).data('lastError', newError);
    if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
      $(element).popover({
        trigger: "manual",
        placement: "auto top",
        content: newError,
        container: "body",
        template: "<div class=\"popover\" role=\"tooltip\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div>"
      });
      if (element.is(':hidden')) {
        $(element).next('span').popover('show').addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        console.log('hidden element');
      }else {
        $(element).popover("show").parents(".form-group").addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        console.log('normal element');
      }
    }
  },    
  success: function (label, element) {
    $(element).popover("hide").parents(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
  },
  rules: {
    "3_nombre[]": {
      maxlength: 500,
      required: {
        depends: function(element){
          var id=$(this).parents('table').attr('id');
          var rut_p=$('#'+id+' #3_rut').val();
          var xurl="vws/ajax_validar_rut.php?rut="+rut_p;
          $.ajax({
            url: xurl,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
              // alert(1);
              if( data==0 ){
                // alert(2);
                if($('.3_rut').val() !='' || $('.3_ape_p').val() !='' || $('.3_ape_m').val() !='' ){
                  // alert(3);
                  return true;
                }else {
                  // alert(4);
                  return false;
                }
                // return true;
              }else {
                // alert(5);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Entonces se entiende que este `required`, debe recibir un 'TRUE' o un 'FALSE'. Pero no lo recibe. Me falta algo, ¿existe algún error que el depurador no está viendo?

Me faltaba describir que la 'xurl' -> 'ajax_vallidar_rut.php' valida el rut en sí (que sea legítimo) y que sea o no mayor a un rango para identificar si es de empresa o de una persona natural. Esto devuelve un '0' o un '1' que es lo que valido luego en el `success` del AJAX.

**UPDATE**

Había encontrado una solución, pero esta desactualizada. Justamente era el tema del `async=false` en el AJAX, quedándome así;

```
"3_ape_p[]": {
maxlength: 500,
required: {
    depends: function(element){
        var id=$(this).parents('table').attr('id');
        var rut_p=$('#'+id+' #3_rut').val();
        var xurl="vws/ajax_validar_rut.php?rut="+rut_p;
        var bRequired=false;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: xurl,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                if( data==1 || data==0 ){
                    if($('.3_rut').val() !='' || $('.3_ape_m').val() !='' || $('.3_direccion').val() !='' || $('.3_num').val() !='' || $('.3_comuna').val() !='' || $('.3_email').val() !='' || $('.3_tel').val() !='' || $('.3_fax').val() !=''){
                        // return true;
                        bRequired=true;
                    }else {
                        // return false;
                        bRequired=false;
                    }
                    // return true;
                }else {
                    // return false;
                    bRequired=false;
                }
            }
        });
        return bRequired;
      }
    }
},
```

Extrayendo la idea que me diste, me queda esto:

```
"3_nombre_prop[]": {
   maxlength: 500,
   required: true,
   remote: {
       xurl: "vws/ajax_validar_rut.php?rut="+$('#'+$(this).parents('table').attr('id')+' #3_rut_prop').val();
       type: "GET",
       data: {
          ape_p: $('.3_ape_p').val(),
          ape_m: $('.3_ape_m').val()
       }
   }
},
```

Pero me dice que tengo un error de sintaxis en la URL.

Tendría que cambiar el `type` y dejarlo como `POST` para enviar el rut por `data`?

Agradecido, como siempre..
MUCHAS GRACIAS!

**UPDATE**

No puedo creer que me fue tan sencillo, GRACIAS @Alvaro por la guía.. Al final lo deje así;

```
"3_nombre_prop[]": {
    maxlength: 500,
    required: true,
    remote: {
        url: "vws/ajax_valida_campos.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {

        }
    }
},
```

Y en el `ajax_valida_campos.php`, quedo así;

```
<?php
  // print_r($_POST);
  $n_cantidad=count($_POST);
  $bValida=false;
  if(intval($n_cantidad)>0)
      $bValida=false;
  else 
      $bValida=true;

  echo $bValida;
?>
```

De esta forma, valido cuando existen datos y cuando no. Estaría correcto?

AGRADECIDO!

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún framework o plugin para controlar la validación del formulario? Si sí, por favor indica cuál para definir mejor el ámbito de la pregunta

Comment: Solo JQUERY validate..

Comment: primero: no sería `xurl` sino `url`; segundo: al final de esa línea debería haber una coma (`,`) y no un punto y coma (`;`). He actualizado el código de mi respuesta, míralo y haz los cambios que necesitarías

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos problemas con el código de arriba:

1. AJAX es una llamada asíncrona, pero intentas usarla de manera síncrona.
2. El ámbito del `return true` o `return false` no es el adecuado.

¿Qué significa esto? En el `depends` realizas la llamada AJAX, que se ejecuta asíncronamente mientras el código de `depends` continúa y termina sin haber obtenido respuesta (problema 1). Incluso si el AJAX fuera síncrono (no recomendado) y llegas a la parte que devuelve `true` o `false`, el valor que se devuelve es dentro de la función `success` y no dentro de `depends` que seguiría sin devolver nada (problema 2).

Esto se podría solucionar haciendo el AJAX síncrono y guardando el valor en una variable que se devolvería en `depends`, pero no es la mejor opción. En lugar de eso, **deberías usar el método interno de jQuery Validate: [`remote`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)**.

`remote` solicita la validación del campo a un recurso remoto usando AJAX. Básicamente es lo mismo que estás intentando hacer, pero ya integrado con el plugin, así que te ahorrarás dolores de cabeza y problemas como los de arriba.

Como puedes ver en el enlace de arriba, la sintaxis de `remote` es muy sencilla y similar a la de AJAX en jQuery, por lo que casi lo tienes ya todo. En tu caso particular sería algo como esto:

> Nota: El siguiente código no ha sido probado y puede contener fallos, la idea es que sirva de referencia para apoyarte y completarlo

```
rules: {
    "3_nombre[]": {
        maxlength: 500,
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: "vws/ajax_validar_rut.php",
            type: "get",
            data: {
                rut: $('#' + $(this).parents('table').attr('id') + ' #3_rut_prop').val(),
                rut3: $('.3_rut').val(),
                ape_p: $('.3_ape_p').val(),
                ape_m: $('.3_ape_m').val()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La idea es que pases todos los parámetros necesarios al servicio que comprueba si el rut es correcto y todas las operaciones se realizarán allí, devolviendo `true` si es válido o `false` si es inválido.

Comment: Creo que lo tengo, no puedo creer que sea tan fácil.
Cambie el `type` a `$_POST`.. en data no envié nada y en el archivo que esta en la URL, solo valide que; en el `$_POST` hubieran datos sino, envía un `false`.

Se entiende?

De todas formas, @Alvaro muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Estimados, cual es la sintaxis correcta, para enviar los datos por `POST` en el `remote` ? 
Pues envío datos y estos no llegan al archivo en la URL.

Comment: @x_Mario para enviar datos por el post, cambia la línea `type: "get"` por `type: "post"`

Comment: Si lo cambie, pero mi consulta iba dirigida a como establezco el valor en `data`. Pero ya lo resolví.. AGRADECIDO!!