# formValidation error con remote validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel, jquery-validate

Mi problema principal era que intentaba obtener un true/false del controlador para asi comprobar la existencia de un item en la BD, [(pueden verlo aca)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35894/por-qu%C3%A9-al-validar-usando-un-plugin-y-ajax-me-relentiza-la-el-sistema). Se resolvio el error, luego vi que uno de los usuarios, de las preguntas que me sugirieron, lo trabajo con jqueryvalidate [(aca la pregunta)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5894/problema-con-resultado-ajax-en-una-regla-required-de-jquery-validate/), entonces se me ocurrio yo hacerlo con el plugin que yo estoy usando, entre a a las opciones del plugin [(aca lo pueden ver)](http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/) se puede observar que manejan de la misma manera las validaciones externas. Entonces use su documentacion e intente hacerlo yo mismo y me presenta problemas, que son los siguiente:

Nuevamente, el de la pregunta anterior:

> javascript?v=1480049567:1145 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

este otro error:

> POST http://localhost:8000/cargos/comprobacion 500 (Internal Server Error)

este chequeo su resultado con Fiddler

> InvalidArgumentException in Builder.php line 1203:Illegal operator and value combination.

y este otro error:

> formValidation.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: b.success is not a function(…)
>   f   @   formValidation.min.js:4
>   validate    @   formValidation.min.js:4
>   validateField   @   formValidation.min.js:1
>   (anonymous function)    @   formValidation.min.js:1
>   (anonymous function)    @   formValidation.min.js:1
>   dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
>   q.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3

Aca en [esta web](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-javascript-validation-plugin-which-should-use-formrequest-rules)  consegui un foro donde hablan acerca de como hacer lo que yo quiero hacer.

Les presento lo que yo he hecho:

Código Ajax formValidation:

```
            $('#form-crear').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                CrearNombre: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'El campo Nombre es requerido'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 5,
                            max: 30,
                            message: 'El Nombre de 5 a 30 caracteres de largo'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                            message: 'El Nombre solo puede contener letras'
                        },
                        remote: {
                            message: 'El Cargo no esta disponible',
                            url: 'cargos/comprobacion',
                            type: 'POST'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Aca el controlador:

```
    public function comprobacion(Request $req) {
        try{
            $isAvailable = true;
            if (Cargos::where('nombre', 'ilike', $req->get('CrearNombre'))->exists()) {
                $isAvailable = false;
            } else {
                $isAvailable = true;
            }
            return \Response::json(array('valid' => $isAvailable));
        }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            $array = array(
                'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                'codigo' => $e->getCode(),
                'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
            );
            return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
        }
}
```

¿Que otra información necesitan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Para el mensaje:

  > javascript?v=1480049567:1145 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

  Seguramente existe una llamada `ajax` la cual tiene configurada `async: false`. Si es así, simplemente quita es configuración.
- Para los mensajes:

  > - POST http://localhost:8000/cargos/comprobacion 500 (Internal Server Error)
  > - InvalidArgumentException in Builder.php line 1203:Illegal operator and value combination.

  - La variable enviada no es `$req->valor`, es `$req->CrearNombre`. Modifica tu consulta así:

    ```
    $sql = Cargos::select('id')->where('nombre', '=', $req->CrearNombre)->get();
    ```

    Ten en cuenta que `$req->CrearNombre` no puede ser `null`.
- Para el mensaje:

  > formValidation.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: b.success is not a function(…) f @ formValidation.min.js:4 validate @ formValidation.min.js:4 validateField @ formValidation.min.js:1 (anonymous function) @ formValidation.min.js:1 (anonymous function) @ formValidation.min.js:1 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3 q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

  **No uses `jQuery v3.x`. `FormValidation` requiere `jQuery` `v1.9.1` o superior, pero menor a `v3`**

Comment: para el 1er error agregue "async: true" y se soluciono, para el 2do lo obtuve como dices :D y yo uso postgres asi q tiene ilike, gracias por la sugerencia de igual forma.

El error que ahora me lanza es:
https://goo.gl/AbWMMZ

Comment: @PabloContreras al abrir ese link solo aparece una imagen... no hay ningún texto u error.

Comment: Copié el texto del error q me envía el plugin formValidation

Comment: @PabloContreras, quieres decir que todavia sigue apareciendo el ultimo error?

Comment: si hermano aun sigue el ultimo error.

Comment: ¿Que versión de `jQuery` estas usando? `formValidaton` requiere v1.9.1 o superior. Intenta agregar un snippet donde se pueda reproducir el error, sino es como manejar a ciegas.

Comment: la ultima 3.1.1
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: snippet.. como cual me recomiendas? primera vez que lo escucho; uso, para detectar errores, la consola de laravel y fiddler 4..

Comment: el proyecto es recien, llevo 3 semanas de haberlo empezado, uso las ultimas versiones de los plugin.

Comment: busque otra versión de formValidation, la v0.6.1 a ver si era problema de la actualización (buscando otras opciones) e igual me lanza el mismo error.

Comment: Acá mas explicito el error: https://goo.gl/IYOWd6

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvió :D crei que cualquier jQuery superior a v1.9.1 me funcionaria cualquiera. Mil gracias por la atención.